# Angular and ngx-translate tag issue

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have this student.component.ts  to construct table output

```
var html = ......

html +='<li><a class="fanta" data-element-id="' + student.Id + '">Set as Draft</a></li>';
return html;
```

Ngx-translate is in such syntax {{ 'Set as Draft' | translate }}
Wonder how to add in?
.

I also have this in angular changeprofile.component.html

```
<sa-big-breadcrumbs [items]="['Profile', 'Change Password']" icon="star" class="styling"></sa-big-breadcrumbs>
```

Wonder how to add in {{ 'Profile' | translate }} and  {{ 'Change Password' | translate }} ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making HTML tags by code (var html ...), one way is to use the translate pipe in your code like this :

```
import { TranslatePipe} from '@ngx-translate/core';


    class YourService {
    
      constructor( private translatPipe: TranslatePipe) {}
    
      YourFunction(value) {
        this.translatPipe.transform(value, 'pipeFilter'); // i.e.

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory that you should use always   two way data binding.

In both the cases which you explained in the question we can solve it by using the attributes   way of deceleration

Example :

In your case it will be something like

<sa-big-breadcrumbs [items]="['Profile', 'Change Password']" icon="star" class="styling" [translate]="PROFILE"></sa-big-breadcrumbs